# Can I create a custom google maps control that forces the map to full-screen?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

For Google Maps, I'm using the JS API (v3.33). I know about the built-in default "fullscreen" control, which works fine. But is there a way to have a custom control button also force the map to go full-screen in the same way as the google maps button does it?

I'm aware of the ["FullScreen API" in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API), but I'm not sure if that's literally all Google Maps is doing, or if they're taking other steps as well? It would be really nice if, like `setZoom(..)` and other methods on the API, there was just a `setFullscreen(true)` and `setFullscreen(false)`, but I don't see those there.

I don't want to fake fullscreen with CSS or anything, I literally just want a way to trigger google-maps going fullscreen in the same way as its normal control does.

I am aware that these can only run in response to user events (clicks, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up picking apart Google's code to see what they do with their fullscreen button. They seem to only call the `requestFullScreen()` JS API (and `exitFullScreen()`). So I made my own button to do that, and it seems to work fine. I also used the CSS `:fullscreen` selector on my map container so that my button toggles its icon between fullscreen and regular modes. Lastly, I first detect if these APIs are supported on a device, and only show the button if so. iOS for example doesn't support it. Bummer.

The tricky part of this is checking not only for all these JS and CSS features, but also their vendor prefixed versions, which use bizarre variations of capitalization or hyphenation between them.